# PHP/Ruby captive portal first domain seems cached

Tags: php, ruby, apache, iptables

I have created a captive portal with iptables

I use what many people seem to use : Users can request DNS, packet marked as 99. 99 means no internet else the user does have access.

When a user visits a page when visiting for example stack overflow. The user gets the disclaimer. He/she clicks on okay. What happened is that the server executes the following rules :

```
`sudo /sbin/iptables -t mangle -I captivePortal 1 -m mac --mac-source {$mac} -j RETURN`;
    `sudo /sbin/iptables -t mangle -I captivePortal 1 -s {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} -j RETURN`;
```

**What i have tried:**

Used sinatra stand alone with thin. Render template with erb. When the user reloads after authenticating they get the disclaimer when visiting the initial domain. When the visit another they dont get the disclaimer page.

Set up apache2 with php, rewritten all in php. added meta tags to prevent caching in the browser but same result. original domain redirects to disclaimer always but other sites are okay.

**What i want to achieve**

Users need to click accept on disclaimer before they can use WIFI.

Edit : Reloading apache2 does correct this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Used rmtrack as described here : http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Using_iptables_and_PHP_to_create_a_captive_portal

```
/usr/sbin/conntrack -L \
    |grep $1 \
    |grep ESTAB \
    |grep 'dport=80' \
    |awk \
        "{ system(\"conntrack -D --orig-src $1 --orig-dst \" \
            substr(\$6,5) \" -p tcp --orig-port-src \" substr(\$7,7) \" \
            --orig-port-dst 80\"); }"
```